# Появление красного индикатора очереди проверки при пустой очереди

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, поддержка, статус-так-задумано

У меня уже неоднократно возникает ситуация, когда в очереди пусто а индикатор горит ядовито красным - очередь Вопросы на переоткрытие. Я думал что у меня в кеше что-то сохранилось, поэтому я сначала просто перезагрузил страницу (не помогло), перезагрузил страницу с очисткой кеша `ctrl+R`(не помогло), полез в настройки страницы чтобы поставить галку `Disable cache` а она там у меня уже стоит(не помогло). Моя система:

1. windows 10x64 версия 1903 (сборка ос 18362.239)
2. браузер - Chrome
3. версия браузера - 75.0.3770.142 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)
4. Руки кривые - две штуки

Может это проблема в системе, либо проблема у сайта, я решил написать на всякий случай :)

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51128821#51128821

Comment: @nomnoms12, значит проблема уже известна, спасибо :)

Comment: Этой проблеме, на самом деле, несколько лет =/

Comment: @Suvitruf, примерно столько, сколько вообще лет этому красному индикатору

Comment: «статус-так-задумано» — да вы издеваетесь

Comment: @andreymal ну, исправлять это никто не собирается   (｡•́︿•̀｡)

Comment: Присоединяюсь к сообществу "красный индикатор". На мой взгляд это мешает, ибо привыкаешь, что он горит, а потом, когда действительно появляются материалы для проверки, то ты не знаешь этого, ибо индикатор всегда горит.

Comment: У меня сегодня тоже самое с очередью "Сообщения низкого качества" :(